# Problem to pass csv file into a function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, base58

I'm finally asking for help for a small project I just can't complete.

I work on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.12 or Python 3.5.2

That's pretty simple:

I have a csv file containing thousands of bitcoin addresses in that format  :

```
12xApR3LKKobfMtPyorsyfpdQt51C1242P
1MqadAMYmwqvJPEYR5UhWHGhupuiXdQ5Pg
1P66WyUGcuPGTKH1ECwmrXoASPR1WP5dfa
1LWb1YtSoQ7m8RreJAEyasHK61jsQqMHGD
1BZnbtBXAKtjrA1suinXrf1s6pjhjPA7oG
166goQjUX3Lh3aN9SEXgcRwpPSBoJWtdDu
1C3pvanq8ZHDGrjfxQU7x8D13DS7d9XjLF
```

I would like to convert them in HASH160 using this function that actually work for sure:

```
adr160 = base58.b58decode_check(adr58).encode('hex')[2:]
```

and write the result in the same format in another text or csv file.

```
88374DB2A14DEA2925B19AF4D4AD84EB94FDE409
156732EBD650DF4AC212F5C8DE5DFBA4AE588B59
E4928C9EFDE55B17603D9539FB649D9457C293EB
...
```

I've tried so many things and yet each time there is a problem preventing me from succeeding.

here are my 2 last attempts:

```
import base58
import csv

adr58 =''

with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    adr58 = csv.reader(csvfile)
    adr160 = base58.b58decode_check(adr58).encode('hex')[2:]

with open("Output.txt", "a+") as text_file:
    text_file.write(adr160)
```

result :

```
" AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'rstrip' "
```

and the second attempt was:

```
import base58
import pandas as pd

adr58 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')


def convert(adr58):
    print ("the address is: ")
    adr160 = base58.b58decode_check(adr58).encode('hex')[2:]

    f = open("hashed.txt", "w")
    f.write(adr160)
    f.close()

convert(adr58)
```

result :

```
" AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rstrip' "
```

How can I do that in a simple way?  I'm at a total loss here.

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: In both cases, you're trying to operate on the object itself, rather than the strings contained in the object. See the examples in the [csvreader()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) docs: "Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile". In the first case, you need to use iteration like `for row in adr58 :`, for the second you would need to use `df.apply()` or `df.iterrows()`

Comment: you were right. I was trying to operate on the object itself. Just a quick read of the section of the doc you recommended and my code is now working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the value per row of the DataFrame, and not on the DaataFrame itself:

```
import base58
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('sample.csv')



def convert(adr58):
    adr58_list = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        print ("the address is: ", df.iloc[:,i])
        adr58_list.append(base58.b58decode_check(df.iloc[:,i]).encode('hex')[2:])

    odf = pd.DataFrame()
    odf['column_name'] = adr58_list
    odf.to_csv('hashed.csv', index = False)

convert(df)
```